# Webservice to open documents from a App_Data folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I need to know if it is possible to use web service which can open files like .docx, .doc, .pdf when one click on a link.

My scenario. I have a form which collects certain user details like Name, address, ... Comments and also upload one or two files  like resume, project report etc..

When form is validated this information is store in database and email is sent to xyz@abc.com email address  with forms details, so that administrator always receives information by email as it is quicker

I need to send uploaded documents either as attachment by email or write a code which can open related documents .

I am not sure if i need web service for this.

Please advice what is the best way to do it.

MY website is asp.net based. C#.

Comment: Sending documents as attachements seems reasonable. What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a webservice in this case.

Just delegate the mailer code to your backend routine (business logic layer), which can pick up files as attachments using your regular `System.Net.Mail`. Use `smtp.SendAsync` instead of `smtp.Send` so that you don't end up blocking your web form. Your backend routine can even be a service like WCF. Or a separate .dll. Just depends on how you have structured your layers.

However, if your mailer code is in the code-behind itself instead of another layer or tier then `SendAsync` can get tricky. Then you have a couple of options:

1. Use the `async` directive on the page to make it an `async` page. Or,
2. Spawn a thread to do the work, something like.... `System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` ...

There are other workarounds as well, like as mentioned in this link: http://blog.jdconley.com/2009/01/fire-and-forget-email-webservices-and.html

I would suggest, you delegate the work to your business logic layer that would make it easy for you.

Of course, you can always use `smtp.Send` to work synchronously, if the overhead is not much.